# JSON won't compile, giving this: Line 33: Parse error on line 34: ...7, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },]} ----------------------^

Tags: json, geojson

I tested it on [GeoJSON Lint](http://geojsonlint.com/). Here is the full error:

`Line 33: Parse error on line 34: ...7, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },]} ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ']'`

Here is the code: https://jsbin.com/yifacocadi/edit?js

Here is Line 33 and 34:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 482, "Kabupaten_": "Kota BEKASI", "kode": "3273", "Ibukota": "Bekasi", "Dsr_Hukum": null, "Provinsi": "Jawa Barat", "Bupati_Wal": "Mochtar Mohamad", "Wakil": "Rachmat Effendi", "Batas_Utar": "Kab. Bekasi", "Batas_Sela": "Kab. Bogor", "Batas_Bara": "DKI Jaya", "Batas_Timu": "Kab. Bekasi", "Lmb_Geo": "Jakarta, Karawang" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 106.900627, -6.400002, 0.0 ], [ 106.901047, -6.398458, 0.0 ], [ 106.901207, -6.39665, 0.0 ], [ 106.90213, -6.39472, 0.0 ], [ 106.903984, -6.391451, 0.0 ], [ 106.90554, -6.388092, 0.0 ], [ 106.906273, -6.384465, 0.0 ], [ 106.90699, -6.382236, 0.0 ], [ 106.907509, -6.38013, 0.0 ], [ 106.908234, -6.377287, 0.0 ], [ 106.909462, -6.374601, 0.0 ], [ 106.910789, -6.370014, 0.0 ], [ 106.9132, -6.366885, 0.0 ], [ 106.914848, -6.363039, 0.0 ], [ 106.915672, -6.360684, 0.0 ], [ 106.916626, -6.355731, 0.0 ], [ 106.916489, -6.353509, 0.0 ], [ 106.915565, -6.348314, 0.0 ], [ 106.915474, -6.346694, 0.0 ], [ 106.915375, -6.345045, 0.0 ], [ 106.916008, -6.342572, 0.0 ], [ 106.915604, -6.339929, 0.0 ], [ 106.91555, -6.335619, 0.0 ], [ 106.916092, -6.332885, 0.0 ], [ 106.916527, -6.330444, 0.0 ], [ 106.918022, -6.328257, 0.0 ], [ 106.919174, -6.32607, 0.0 ], [ 106.921188, -6.323135, 0.0 ], [ 106.922012, -6.321393, 0.0 ], [ 106.922112, -6.321179, 0.0 ], [ 106.922569, -6.318879, 0.0 ], [ 106.922684, -6.31612, 0.0 ], [ 106.92263, -6.313534, 0.0 ], [ 106.922569, -6.311408, 0.0 ], [ 106.922226, -6.306695, 0.0 ], [ 106.920639, -6.302841, 0.0 ], [ 106.913826, -6.301197, 0.0 ], [ 106.912445, -6.299705, 0.0 ], [ 106.912331, -6.299335, 0.0 ], [ 106.911812, -6.297695, 0.0 ], [ 106.911697, -6.295396, 0.0 ], [ 106.911751, -6.29304, 0.0 ], [ 106.911812, -6.290339, 0.0 ], [ 106.912209, -6.285801, 0.0 ], [ 106.912331, -6.283441, 0.0 ], [ 106.912445, -6.280854, 0.0 ], [ 106.912041, -6.277981, 0.0 ], [ 106.910255, -6.276778, 0.0 ], [ 106.908127, -6.275346, 0.0 ], [ 106.907494, -6.272646, 0.0 ], [ 106.907379, -6.270232, 0.0 ], [ 106.907616, -6.267307, 0.0 ], [ 106.909164, -6.263964, 0.0 ], [ 106.911179, -6.262925, 0.0 ], [ 106.913773, -6.262172, 0.0 ], [ 106.917397, -6.261532, 0.0 ], [ 106.922401, -6.259912, 0.0 ], [ 106.925629, -6.258875, 0.0 ], [ 106.928909, -6.258232, 0.0 ], [ 106.931847, -6.25788, 0.0 ], [ 106.936394, -6.257008, 0.0 ], [ 106.940712, -6.256367, 0.0 ], [ 106.945602, -6.25469, 0.0 ], [ 106.945663, -6.25239, 0.0 ], [ 106.945778, -6.249804, 0.0 ], [ 106.946236, -6.246814, 0.0 ], [ 106.946701, -6.244285, 0.0 ], [ 106.947548, -6.24026, 0.0 ], [ 106.949638, -6.235025, 0.0 ], [ 106.951706, -6.23025, 0.0 ], [ 106.953575, -6.228466, 0.0 ], [ 106.955391, -6.222713, 0.0 ], [ 106.963341, -6.212121, 0.0 ], [ 106.966217, -6.20723, 0.0 ], [ 106.96846, -6.203374, 0.0 ], [ 106.970291, -6.198889, 0.0 ], [ 106.971573, -6.194287, 0.0 ], [ 106.972488, -6.188538, 0.0 ], [ 106.972893, -6.185318, 0.0 ], [ 106.973068, -6.179743, 0.0 ], [ 106.972954, -6.174169, 0.0 ], [ 106.978043, -6.171785, 0.0 ], [ 106.982628, -6.166146, 0.0 ], [ 106.985931, -6.165713, 0.0 ], [ 106.991524, -6.166375, 0.0 ], [ 106.994148, -6.166396, 0.0 ], [ 106.99688, -6.166165, 0.0 ], [ 107.003967, -6.166914, 0.0 ], [ 107.00621, -6.16695, 0.0 ], [ 107.008659, -6.167095, 0.0 ], [ 107.012039, -6.16734, 0.0 ], [ 107.012245, -6.176519, 0.0 ], [ 107.011826, -6.179852, 0.0 ], [ 107.0121, -6.18398, 0.0 ], [ 107.013519, -6.187364, 0.0 ], [ 107.015533, -6.189384, 0.0 ], [ 107.017426, -6.190366, 0.0 ], [ 107.019333, -6.191158, 0.0 ], [ 107.022217, -6.191817, 0.0 ], [ 107.023727, -6.193829, 0.0 ], [ 107.027443, -6.193086, 0.0 ], [ 107.032524, -6.193823, 0.0 ], [ 107.034721, -6.195148, 0.0 ], [ 107.036453, -6.197819, 0.0 ], [ 107.037369, -6.204127, 0.0 ], [ 107.035828, -6.209923, 0.0 ], [ 107.034653, -6.213435, 0.0 ], [ 107.033569, -6.215954, 0.0 ], [ 107.032104, -6.21777, 0.0 ], [ 107.036774, -6.219177, 0.0 ], [ 107.040123, -6.221282, 0.0 ], [ 107.041771, -6.223825, 0.0 ], [ 107.043777, -6.227493, 0.0 ], [ 107.044609, -6.230995, 0.0 ], [ 107.044762, -6.234591, 0.0 ], [ 107.044617, -6.236915, 0.0 ], [ 107.044098, -6.24012, 0.0 ], [ 107.043602, -6.242078, 0.0 ], [ 107.043091, -6.24448, 0.0 ], [ 107.042534, -6.246438, 0.0 ], [ 107.041031, -6.249119, 0.0 ], [ 107.038139, -6.252371, 0.0 ], [ 107.034882, -6.253925, 0.0 ], [ 107.032532, -6.255198, 0.0 ], [ 107.029167, -6.256919, 0.0 ], [ 107.026184, -6.259556, 0.0 ], [ 107.024818, -6.261606, 0.0 ], [ 107.024063, -6.263644, 0.0 ], [ 107.023567, -6.265666, 0.0 ], [ 107.020844, -6.275411, 0.0 ], [ 107.019844, -6.279348, 0.0 ], [ 107.018837, -6.282735, 0.0 ], [ 107.021362, -6.283368, 0.0 ], [ 107.023827, -6.282668, 0.0 ], [ 107.02607, -6.281436, 0.0 ], [ 107.028053, -6.280326, 0.0 ], [ 107.031158, -6.279446, 0.0 ], [ 107.033752, -6.279615, 0.0 ], [ 107.035797, -6.280176, 0.0 ], [ 107.039528, -6.282055, 0.0 ], [ 107.042007, -6.283067, 0.0 ], [ 107.044518, -6.284672, 0.0 ], [ 107.04509, -6.288382, 0.0 ], [ 107.045105, -6.291003, 0.0 ], [ 107.044891, -6.2936, 0.0 ], [ 107.045166, -6.297558, 0.0 ], [ 107.045357, -6.301198, 0.0 ], [ 107.04557, -6.303865, 0.0 ], [ 107.045174, -6.308721, 0.0 ], [ 107.04467, -6.310975, 0.0 ], [ 107.043831, -6.316522, 0.0 ], [ 107.043526, -6.319625, 0.0 ], [ 107.0429, -6.321686, 0.0 ], [ 107.041824, -6.324368, 0.0 ], [ 107.03685, -6.325859, 0.0 ], [ 107.033524, -6.32644, 0.0 ], [ 107.030403, -6.327024, 0.0 ], [ 107.028366, -6.327604, 0.0 ], [ 107.025902, -6.32953, 0.0 ], [ 107.025307, -6.333517, 0.0 ], [ 107.025024, -6.336387, 0.0 ], [ 107.024735, -6.339744, 0.0 ], [ 107.024216, -6.344079, 0.0 ], [ 107.02404, -6.347281, 0.0 ], [ 107.023697, -6.349833, 0.0 ], [ 107.021805, -6.353249, 0.0 ], [ 107.016792, -6.352216, 0.0 ], [ 107.0131, -6.352833, 0.0 ], [ 107.010719, -6.354761, 0.0 ], [ 107.009781, -6.356733, 0.0 ], [ 107.009026, -6.360061, 0.0 ], [ 107.008522, -6.362125, 0.0 ], [ 107.00634, -6.364986, 0.0 ], [ 107.004715, -6.366271, 0.0 ], [ 107.001518, -6.36772, 0.0 ], [ 106.99231, -6.37237, 0.0 ], [ 106.984642, -6.37687, 0.0 ], [ 106.97184, -6.367567, 0.0 ], [ 106.970581, -6.364696, 0.0 ], [ 106.96978, -6.360962, 0.0 ], [ 106.970009, -6.35895, 0.0 ], [ 106.970924, -6.355212, 0.0 ], [ 106.971558, -6.352107, 0.0 ], [ 106.972649, -6.348886, 0.0 ], [ 106.975365, -6.34411, 0.0 ], [ 106.976341, -6.341637, 0.0 ], [ 106.977562, -6.337769, 0.0 ], [ 106.978203, -6.335708, 0.0 ], [ 106.978874, -6.332612, 0.0 ], [ 106.978531, -6.330199, 0.0 ], [ 106.978012, -6.326407, 0.0 ], [ 106.97773, -6.323304, 0.0 ], [ 106.978416, -6.319854, 0.0 ], [ 106.979744, -6.316978, 0.0 ], [ 106.980263, -6.314562, 0.0 ], [ 106.978844, -6.31236, 0.0 ], [ 106.977959, -6.310057, 0.0 ], [ 106.976898, -6.307342, 0.0 ], [ 106.974304, -6.30498, 0.0 ], [ 106.972885, -6.303942, 0.0 ], [ 106.971588, -6.303087, 0.0 ], [ 106.970505, -6.302597, 0.0 ], [ 106.96685, -6.303036, 0.0 ], [ 106.964027, -6.304479, 0.0 ], [ 106.96138, -6.306841, 0.0 ], [ 106.960686, -6.308854, 0.0 ], [ 106.960197, -6.31194, 0.0 ], [ 106.958488, -6.323687, 0.0 ], [ 106.957397, -6.328101, 0.0 ], [ 106.957855, -6.333401, 0.0 ], [ 106.956833, -6.335472, 0.0 ], [ 106.954872, -6.33743, 0.0 ], [ 106.952339, -6.33939, 0.0 ], [ 106.950439, -6.34221, 0.0 ], [ 106.949677, -6.344355, 0.0 ], [ 106.949158, -6.346147, 0.0 ], [ 106.945793, -6.352927, 0.0 ], [ 106.946365, -6.358521, 0.0 ], [ 106.946503, -6.36163, 0.0 ], [ 106.946098, -6.365556, 0.0 ], [ 106.945374, -6.368652, 0.0 ], [ 106.944954, -6.370739, 0.0 ], [ 106.94355, -6.376424, 0.0 ], [ 106.94297, -6.380939, 0.0 ], [ 106.942703, -6.383049, 0.0 ], [ 106.941849, -6.385815, 0.0 ], [ 106.941124, -6.386576, 0.0 ], [ 106.939552, -6.388263, 0.0 ], [ 106.937073, -6.390041, 0.0 ], [ 106.934578, -6.391163, 0.0 ], [ 106.932869, -6.392235, 0.0 ], [ 106.931587, -6.394413, 0.0 ], [ 106.929123, -6.397693, 0.0 ], [ 106.927841, -6.399617, 0.0 ], [ 106.927185, -6.40156, 0.0 ], [ 106.922722, -6.403424, 0.0 ], [ 106.919601, -6.402782, 0.0 ], [ 106.916275, -6.402369, 0.0 ], [ 106.912582, -6.402817, 0.0 ], [ 106.910187, -6.404355, 0.0 ], [ 106.909378, -6.403716, 0.0 ], [ 106.906471, -6.404472, 0.0 ], [ 106.903725, -6.404428, 0.0 ], [ 106.901611, -6.402703, 0.0 ], [ 106.900627, -6.400002, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 483, "Kabupaten_": "Kota CIKARANG", "kode": null, "Ibukota": null, "Dsr_Hukum": null, "Provinsi": "Jawa Barat", "Bupati_Wal": null, "Wakil": null, "Batas_Utar": "Kab. Bekasi", "Batas_Sela": "Kab. Bogor", "Batas_Bara": "Kota Bekasi & Kab. Bekasi", "Batas_Timu": "Kab. Karawang", "Lmb_Geo": "Jakarta, Karawang" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 106.984642, -6.37687, 0.0 ], [ 106.99231, -6.37237, 0.0 ], [ 107.001518, -6.36772, 0.0 ], [ 107.004715, -6.366271, 0.0 ], [ 107.00634, -6.364986, 0.0 ], [ 107.008522, -6.362125, 0.0 ], [ 107.009026, -6.360061, 0.0 ], [ 107.009781, -6.356733, 0.0 ], [ 107.010719, -6.354761, 0.0 ], [ 107.0131, -6.352833, 0.0 ], [ 107.016792, -6.352216, 0.0 ], [ 107.021805, -6.353249, 0.0 ], [ 107.023697, -6.349833, 0.0 ], [ 107.02404, -6.347281, 0.0 ], [ 107.024216, -6.344079, 0.0 ], [ 107.024735, -6.339744, 0.0 ], [ 107.025024, -6.336387, 0.0 ], [ 107.025307, -6.333517, 0.0 ], [ 107.025902, -6.32953, 0.0 ], [ 107.028366, -6.327604, 0.0 ], [ 107.030403, -6.327024, 0.0 ], [ 107.033524, -6.32644, 0.0 ], [ 107.03685, -6.325859, 0.0 ], [ 107.041824, -6.324368, 0.0 ], [ 107.0429, -6.321686, 0.0 ], [ 107.043526, -6.319625, 0.0 ], [ 107.043831, -6.316522, 0.0 ], [ 107.04467, -6.310975, 0.0 ], [ 107.045174, -6.308721, 0.0 ], [ 107.04557, -6.303865, 0.0 ], [ 107.04911, -6.304598, 0.0 ], [ 107.056068, -6.304521, 0.0 ], [ 107.060364, -6.304231, 0.0 ], [ 107.064217, -6.303934, 0.0 ], [ 107.06385, -6.30156, 0.0 ], [ 107.063377, -6.299607, 0.0 ], [ 107.063171, -6.296686, 0.0 ], [ 107.063896, -6.293971, 0.0 ], [ 107.066505, -6.290926, 0.0 ], [ 107.070625, -6.286067, 0.0 ], [ 107.071594, -6.283524, 0.0 ], [ 107.072281, -6.281632, 0.0 ], [ 107.072655, -6.277135, 0.0 ], [ 107.073608, -6.273197, 0.0 ], [ 107.076523, -6.268487, 0.0 ], [ 107.078247, -6.264964, 0.0 ], [ 107.080315, -6.261593, 0.0 ], [ 107.081612, -6.258654, 0.0 ], [ 107.083008, -6.254808, 0.0 ], [ 107.083862, -6.251693, 0.0 ], [ 107.084595, -6.247096, 0.0 ], [ 107.085693, -6.243392, 0.0 ], [ 107.087051, -6.240623, 0.0 ], [ 107.08857, -6.238386, 0.0 ], [ 107.091721, -6.233046, 0.0 ], [ 107.09269, -6.230821, 0.0 ], [ 107.093033, -6.227845, 0.0 ], [ 107.09388, -6.225533, 0.0 ], [ 107.093575, -6.223435, 0.0 ], [ 107.090599, -6.21529, 0.0 ], [ 107.089737, -6.212697, 0.0 ], [ 107.0886, -6.209782, 0.0 ], [ 107.086571, -6.204612, 0.0 ], [ 107.085297, -6.201251, 0.0 ], [ 107.083832, -6.197845, 0.0 ], [ 107.082542, -6.194251, 0.0 ], [ 107.081612, -6.190324, 0.0 ], [ 107.081459, -6.187849, 0.0 ], [ 107.082436, -6.185433, 0.0 ], [ 107.084267, -6.183475, 0.0 ], [ 107.087021, -6.181659, 0.0 ], [ 107.089653, -6.179736, 0.0 ], [ 107.091843, -6.177868, 0.0 ], [ 107.094223, -6.177103, 0.0 ], [ 107.096603, -6.176444, 0.0 ], [ 107.098877, -6.175762, 0.0 ], [ 107.102394, -6.17622, 0.0 ], [ 107.104309, -6.177054, 0.0 ], [ 107.106033, -6.180275, 0.0 ], [ 107.106056, -6.182389, 0.0 ], [ 107.106293, -6.188355, 0.0 ], [ 107.106689, -6.192526, 0.0 ], [ 107.107719, -6.194298, 0.0 ], [ 107.109818, -6.196425, 0.0 ], [ 107.112617, -6.198563, 0.0 ], [ 107.115257, -6.200022, 0.0 ], [ 107.117615, -6.200674, 0.0 ], [ 107.122459, -6.205551, 0.0 ], [ 107.124771, -6.20878, 0.0 ], [ 107.12693, -6.211162, 0.0 ], [ 107.128494, -6.213492, 0.0 ], [ 107.130165, -6.214787, 0.0 ], [ 107.132919, -6.215931, 0.0 ], [ 107.136879, -6.221725, 0.0 ], [ 107.138329, -6.224771, 0.0 ], [ 107.139854, -6.226974, 0.0 ], [ 107.141647, -6.228567, 0.0 ], [ 107.144058, -6.230974, 0.0 ], [ 107.146828, -6.232562, 0.0 ], [ 107.150375, -6.233845, 0.0 ], [ 107.15316, -6.235835, 0.0 ], [ 107.154747, -6.238039, 0.0 ], [ 107.155716, -6.240697, 0.0 ], [ 107.156586, -6.243015, 0.0 ], [ 107.159599, -6.241352, 0.0 ], [ 107.161102, -6.238733, 0.0 ], [ 107.161224, -6.233767, 0.0 ], [ 107.160484, -6.229865, 0.0 ], [ 107.160378, -6.227432, 0.0 ], [ 107.160332, -6.225211, 0.0 ], [ 107.161041, -6.222073, 0.0 ], [ 107.162308, -6.218393, 0.0 ], [ 107.165787, -6.211388, 0.0 ], [ 107.167603, -6.208775, 0.0 ], [ 107.170685, -6.202651, 0.0 ], [ 107.172394, -6.198154, 0.0 ], [ 107.17308, -6.194867, 0.0 ], [ 107.174286, -6.189644, 0.0 ], [ 107.175217, -6.184838, 0.0 ], [ 107.175362, -6.179957, 0.0 ], [ 107.177238, -6.170072, 0.0 ], [ 107.177345, -6.167346, 0.0 ], [ 107.180786, -6.169178, 0.0 ], [ 107.184006, -6.173522, 0.0 ], [ 107.185982, -6.175731, 0.0 ], [ 107.188866, -6.178906, 0.0 ], [ 107.190338, -6.180601, 0.0 ], [ 107.192276, -6.182133, 0.0 ], [ 107.195412, -6.184319, 0.0 ], [ 107.200439, -6.18736, 0.0 ], [ 107.212082, -6.193785, 0.0 ], [ 107.216179, -6.19662, 0.0 ], [ 107.218704, -6.197317, 0.0 ], [ 107.22139, -6.19865, 0.0 ], [ 107.223457, -6.199169, 0.0 ], [ 107.225388, -6.200025, 0.0 ], [ 107.227272, -6.201113, 0.0 ], [ 107.230408, -6.203066, 0.0 ], [ 107.239616, -6.208691, 0.0 ], [ 107.23864, -6.212755, 0.0 ], [ 107.237701, -6.215721, 0.0 ], [ 107.236732, -6.219532, 0.0 ], [ 107.235847, -6.223112, 0.0 ], [ 107.235603, -6.225941, 0.0 ], [ 107.235527, -6.228307, 0.0 ], [ 107.235176, -6.230331, 0.0 ], [ 107.23497, -6.232337, 0.0 ], [ 107.232216, -6.233962, 0.0 ], [ 107.228516, -6.231725, 0.0 ], [ 107.223366, -6.228491, 0.0 ], [ 107.222969, -6.233009, 0.0 ], [ 107.222527, -6.235687, 0.0 ], [ 107.221931, -6.23832, 0.0 ], [ 107.22094, -6.240862, 0.0 ], [ 107.219147, -6.239248, 0.0 ], [ 107.215202, -6.236182, 0.0 ], [ 107.212601, -6.233666, 0.0 ], [ 107.210159, -6.231745, 0.0 ], [ 107.20697, -6.230383, 0.0 ], [ 107.203957, -6.229848, 0.0 ], [ 107.201256, -6.228029, 0.0 ], [ 107.200058, -6.235472, 0.0 ], [ 107.199234, -6.239053, 0.0 ], [ 107.198807, -6.241795, 0.0 ], [ 107.198669, -6.243927, 0.0 ], [ 107.198601, -6.251643, 0.0 ], [ 107.198357, -6.253838, 0.0 ], [ 107.197624, -6.256934, 0.0 ], [ 107.195053, -6.260064, 0.0 ], [ 107.192642, -6.261378, 0.0 ], [ 107.189629, -6.262048, 0.0 ], [ 107.187447, -6.262435, 0.0 ], [ 107.185555, -6.263314, 0.0 ], [ 107.18428, -6.264943, 0.0 ], [ 107.186562, -6.265973, 0.0 ], [ 107.191429, -6.267299, 0.0 ], [ 107.195305, -6.266748, 0.0 ], [ 107.19783, -6.265923, 0.0 ], [ 107.203926, -6.263167, 0.0 ], [ 107.205635, -6.261947, 0.0 ], [ 107.209801, -6.259794, 0.0 ], [ 107.212067, -6.259155, 0.0 ], [ 107.217194, -6.258857, 0.0 ], [ 107.221107, -6.258688, 0.0 ], [ 107.226387, -6.259027, 0.0 ], [ 107.231453, -6.260525, 0.0 ], [ 107.233536, -6.261446, 0.0 ], [ 107.233749, -6.263881, 0.0 ], [ 107.234192, -6.266298, 0.0 ], [ 107.234795, -6.269628, 0.0 ], [ 107.235313, -6.275006, 0.0 ], [ 107.235451, -6.278433, 0.0 ], [ 107.235718, -6.282475, 0.0 ], [ 107.239784, -6.283196, 0.0 ], [ 107.243141, -6.283737, 0.0 ], [ 107.247322, -6.285136, 0.0 ], [ 107.251122, -6.2882, 0.0 ], [ 107.255104, -6.292512, 0.0 ], [ 107.253685, -6.294786, 0.0 ], [ 107.251617, -6.29617, 0.0 ], [ 107.249367, -6.295658, 0.0 ], [ 107.247787, -6.298302, 0.0 ], [ 107.24482, -6.300955, 0.0 ], [ 107.241943, -6.300788, 0.0 ], [ 107.2397, -6.299242, 0.0 ], [ 107.238144, -6.300682, 0.0 ], [ 107.238777, -6.303382, 0.0 ], [ 107.238602, -6.305451, 0.0 ], [ 107.237282, -6.307466, 0.0 ], [ 107.234978, -6.308275, 0.0 ], [ 107.232674, -6.307648, 0.0 ], [ 107.23037, -6.305871, 0.0 ], [ 107.228668, -6.307759, 0.0 ], [ 107.226746, -6.311266, 0.0 ], [ 107.224098, -6.314694, 0.0 ], [ 107.224152, -6.317166, 0.0 ], [ 107.224556, -6.320096, 0.0 ], [ 107.221565, -6.324183, 0.0 ], [ 107.220833, -6.326109, 0.0 ], [ 107.219948, -6.328439, 0.0 ], [ 107.220932, -6.331828, 0.0 ], [ 107.222198, -6.333633, 0.0 ], [ 107.224152, -6.336231, 0.0 ], [ 107.22496, -6.339333, 0.0 ], [ 107.225243, -6.341516, 0.0 ], [ 107.224785, -6.343644, 0.0 ], [ 107.225761, -6.34558, 0.0 ], [ 107.226746, -6.350249, 0.0 ], [ 107.225304, -6.352379, 0.0 ], [ 107.223518, -6.353647, 0.0 ], [ 107.221275, -6.354284, 0.0 ], [ 107.219147, -6.353887, 0.0 ], [ 107.216896, -6.352857, 0.0 ], [ 107.21431, -6.354513, 0.0 ], [ 107.214363, -6.357444, 0.0 ], [ 107.214134, -6.360031, 0.0 ], [ 107.213326, -6.363366, 0.0 ], [ 107.211601, -6.365438, 0.0 ], [ 107.209702, -6.367339, 0.0 ], [ 107.20826, -6.369354, 0.0 ], [ 107.207108, -6.371598, 0.0 ], [ 107.205757, -6.375338, 0.0 ], [ 107.209068, -6.373835, 0.0 ], [ 107.211258, -6.372968, 0.0 ], [ 107.213326, -6.376297, 0.0 ], [ 107.215569, -6.378591, 0.0 ], [ 107.217011, -6.379983, 0.0 ], [ 107.220634, -6.385362, 0.0 ], [ 107.221619, -6.388595, 0.0 ], [ 107.221443, -6.390606, 0.0 ], [ 107.221039, -6.393711, 0.0 ], [ 107.221382, -6.395706, 0.0 ], [ 107.223282, -6.399004, 0.0 ], [ 107.221787, -6.405648, 0.0 ], [ 107.221382, -6.40789, 0.0 ], [ 107.220001, -6.40979, 0.0 ], [ 107.217293, -6.41014, 0.0 ], [ 107.215225, -6.411122, 0.0 ], [ 107.21344, -6.41239, 0.0 ], [ 107.21286, -6.414748, 0.0 ], [ 107.212173, -6.417106, 0.0 ], [ 107.209755, -6.417915, 0.0 ], [ 107.207512, -6.417116, 0.0 ], [ 107.206413, -6.419359, 0.0 ], [ 107.206818, -6.421715, 0.0 ], [ 107.205956, -6.423671, 0.0 ], [ 107.204742, -6.428214, 0.0 ], [ 107.205032, -6.430282, 0.0 ], [ 107.20549, -6.432982, 0.0 ], [ 107.206009, -6.4362, 0.0 ], [ 107.207047, -6.439589, 0.0 ], [ 107.20826, -6.443264, 0.0 ], [ 107.20929, -6.446256, 0.0 ], [ 107.210556, -6.449581, 0.0 ], [ 107.211655, -6.452165, 0.0 ], [ 107.21257, -6.45406, 0.0 ], [ 107.213379, -6.456184, 0.0 ], [ 107.21418, -6.458251, 0.0 ], [ 107.213898, -6.461471, 0.0 ], [ 107.213203, -6.464346, 0.0 ], [ 107.211937, -6.466475, 0.0 ], [ 107.210152, -6.467628, 0.0 ], [ 107.20768, -6.468151, 0.0 ], [ 107.203705, -6.467642, 0.0 ], [ 107.202271, -6.465806, 0.0 ], [ 107.199738, -6.46426, 0.0 ], [ 107.197144, -6.463921, 0.0 ], [ 107.195358, -6.464844, 0.0 ], [ 107.193054, -6.467263, 0.0 ], [ 107.191269, -6.468761, 0.0 ], [ 107.189484, -6.470087, 0.0 ], [ 107.186203, -6.471818, 0.0 ], [ 107.183784, -6.473548, 0.0 ], [ 107.18235, -6.476314, 0.0 ], [ 107.181137, -6.478784, 0.0 ], [ 107.179756, -6.480511, 0.0 ], [ 107.177452, -6.481838, 0.0 ], [ 107.175613, -6.483796, 0.0 ], [ 107.176155, -6.488254, 0.0 ], [ 107.176422, -6.490461, 0.0 ], [ 107.176399, -6.494124, 0.0 ], [ 107.173866, -6.492348, 0.0 ], [ 107.17041, -6.489942, 0.0 ], [ 107.167526, -6.487879, 0.0 ], [ 107.164879, -6.486104, 0.0 ], [ 107.161026, -6.483699, 0.0 ], [ 107.157455, -6.48158, 0.0 ], [ 107.150932, -6.477887, 0.0 ], [ 107.148186, -6.476257, 0.0 ], [ 107.14312, -6.47374, 0.0 ], [ 107.140541, -6.472511, 0.0 ], [ 107.134598, -6.469678, 0.0 ], [ 107.129189, -6.466645, 0.0 ], [ 107.124756, -6.464586, 0.0 ], [ 107.119743, -6.462011, 0.0 ], [ 107.115311, -6.459378, 0.0 ], [ 107.112854, -6.457693, 0.0 ], [ 107.106621, -6.45342, 0.0 ], [ 107.095566, -6.446032, 0.0 ], [ 107.091599, -6.44381, 0.0 ], [ 107.089638, -6.442712, 0.0 ], [ 107.085892, -6.440249, 0.0 ], [ 107.081917, -6.437557, 0.0 ], [ 107.078926, -6.435381, 0.0 ], [ 107.071381, -6.42919, 0.0 ], [ 107.068741, -6.426534, 0.0 ], [ 107.06488, -6.422652, 0.0 ], [ 107.059464, -6.415883, 0.0 ], [ 107.0569, -6.411829, 0.0 ], [ 107.055878, -6.410217, 0.0 ], [ 107.05423, -6.407726, 0.0 ], [ 107.052094, -6.404921, 0.0 ], [ 107.048241, -6.401928, 0.0 ], [ 107.045074, -6.400799, 0.0 ], [ 107.043221, -6.400411, 0.0 ], [ 107.041275, -6.399994, 0.0 ], [ 107.037071, -6.399094, 0.0 ], [ 107.032005, -6.398071, 0.0 ], [ 107.026711, -6.396761, 0.0 ], [ 107.015999, -6.394085, 0.0 ], [ 107.009415, -6.391266, 0.0 ], [ 107.007187, -6.390312, 0.0 ], [ 107.002335, -6.387471, 0.0 ], [ 106.998177, -6.384908, 0.0 ], [ 106.995102, -6.382868, 0.0 ], [ 106.989922, -6.380007, 0.0 ], [ 106.984642, -6.37687, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } },
```

What's happening here? Oddly, this one: http://jsbin.com/xapohodoca/edit?js works albeit with different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing comma at the end of line 34. Remove it and it should parse fine.

Comment: Yeah just found out that too! That goddamn comma. Thanks.